# Nodejs times out POST request with files bigger than 6gigabytes due to server timeout

Tags: node.js, express, multer-s3, connect-timeout

Im using multer to upload `FormData` to server,file binary alongside some text/objects.
Problem arises with files above 4~5gbs where post request is in pending state and than after a while it returns with `POST http://localhost:5000/upload net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`
What i've done is that i made middleware that does `req.setTimeout` that solution didnt work,i went and tried `req.connection.setTimout` same result. Afterwards with these attempts i just tested by putting globally `server.timeout` to some high amount,same thing.
After this failed attempt i went ahead i tried adding `connect-timeout` middleware library to the upload endpoint but no change.
After all these tries i then went ahead and asked chatGPT aswell that could be the possible issue with these timeouts and it gave me 2 different answers,1st answer was that connection_reset could be client "disconnecting" or closing connection,so i went ahead and added high number `timeout` to `axios` method im using to make a post request and that didnt help either. I'm wondering if there's maybe `socket` object that handles this closing/opening of connections but again i tried `req.connection` timeout and it did nothing.

Any help would be appreciated if anyone ever came accross this problem.